# Gitlab 9.5 build trigger not working as expected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We're on `Gitlab EE 9.5.0-ee 36112e7`.

I have question about Build Triggers. I have a setup where a build is triggered every week via Jenkins using a `curl` trigger. This job typically shows up with a label `API` under `Pipelines`, and when I click on it, I can see any variables in the right rail.

However, with this recent Gitlab version, that's not happening anymore. Any such triggered jobs aren't being labeled as before, and I don't see the variables either. So, the following logic, for e.g, never fires (prolly because `CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED` is not set):

```yaml
  script:
- |
  if [ "$CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED" = "true" ]; then
    if [ "$BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY" != "Jenkins" ]; then
      echo "This build does not seem to be triggered by Jenkins. Skipping..."
      exit 0;
    fi;
  fi;
```

Any idea why?

And, here's the `curl` trigger I use in Jenkins:

```bsh
curl -kf -X POST \
     -F token="$TOKEN" \
     -F ref="master" \
     -F "variables[BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY]=Jenkins" \
     -F "variables[DATE]=$(date +'%Y%m%d')" \
      "https://gitlab.host.com/api/v4/projects/<id>/trigger/pipeline"
```

The `TOKEN` above is a Trigger token from that project's `/settings/ci_cd` page.

Basically, even though the above command starts a new build, it's not being seen as a *triggered* build. I even re-generated a token to use with the Jenkins script, but that also didn't help.

This exact same setup was working before.

**Edit 1:**

So, I updated the `script` in the CI to echo these variables when triggered, and even though the `$BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY` variable is appearing with the expected value, it's the `$CI_PIPELINE_TRIGGERED` variable that's empty, causing my logic to falter. Which probably explains why the build is not marked as `by API` in the Pipelines view.

I'm still not sure why :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. This bug happened in 9.5 because we changed where to store triggered variables for better architecture. We already fixed this problem and the patch will go into 10.0.

We also consider a next patch release (9.5.x) for fixing this regression. For users don’t want to upgrade to 10.0 immediately.

Here is the issue tracker on CE repository; https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37559

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @dosuken123. Since this happened, we upgraded to `10.x`, and I can confirm that the issue is resolved :)!

Answer (score 0):

I experience some unexpected behavior with triggers as well.
Try to use form-urlencoding instead of multipart-form:

```
curl -vk \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "token=$TOKEN&ref=master&variables[BUILD_TRIGGERED_BY]=Jenkins7&variables[DATE]=$(date +'%Y%m%d')" \
https://gitlab.host.com/api/v4/projects/<id>/trigger/pipeline
```

I use GitLab Community Edition 9.3.9 and the variables are then showing up again.
However, this still does not mark the pipeline run with 'API' - this only seems to work with [legacy triggers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#legacy-triggers).